# Summarize values in tuple dictionary to new dictionary in c#

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
Dictionary<(K1, K2), int> dict1;
```

I would like to create a new dictionary from it where all the *int* values matching only on `K1` are summarized and put into a new dictionary like:

```
Dictionary<K1, int> dict2;
```

I have had a look at using `ToDictionary` with something like this:

```
var dict2 = new Dictionary<K1, int>();
var values = dict1.ToDictionary(c => c.Key.Item1);
foreach (var v in values)
{
    dict2[v.Key] += v.Value;
}
```

This wont work since `ToDictionary` returns something like this

```
Dictionary<K1, KeyValuePair<(K1, K2), int>>
```

How can I retrieve a datastructure from `dict1` that allows me to summarize all the values that share `K1` in the tuple key and then store that in a new dictionary like `dict2` using `K1` as key mapped to the summarized *int* values?

Comment: That was foozing muh minds. Did you try this overload? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548657(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ToDictionary(keySelector)` projects into a `Dictionary<TKey, T>`. In your case `T` is `KeyValuePair<(K1,K2), int>`, so it wouldn't work as you expected it to be. You need to use `ToDictionary(keySelector, valueSelector)` instead.

However, since the `key` isn't unique you will run into issue, so you will need to use a `GroupBy` to avoid this:

```
var dict2 = dict1
    .GroupBy(x => x.Key.Item1)
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, g => g.Sum(kvp => kvp.Value));
```

Comment: What are the performance impact of doing this if `dict1` is pretty big? If I only care a about a specific value of `K1`, can it be modified using `select` somehow to only extract the tuples where `K1 == 1` for example?

Comment: @span Not sure why you need a dictionary with a single key, but it can be done using `.Where`(which constrains) instead of `.Select`(which projects/shapes): dict1.Where(x => x.Key.Item1).GroupBy(...).ToDictionary(...). However at this point, it would be more efficient if you just write: new Dictionary<K1, int> { [1] = dict1.Where(...).Sum(x => x.Value) }. As for the performance, I can not answer.

Comment: Completely agree, a one key dict seems useless. So a summary of all values for a k1 would something like: `int sum = dict1.Where(x => x.Key.Item1 == k1).Sum(x => x.Value)`?